# Using DOMDocument PHP classes on simple XML file

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

My XML document is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<userSettings>
    <tables>
        <table id="supertable">
            <userTabLayout id="A">{"id":"colidgoeshereX"}</userTabLayout>
            <userTabLayout id="B">{"id":"colidgoeshereY"}</userTabLayout>
        </table>
        <table id="almost-supertable">
            <userTabLayout id="A">{"id":"colidgoeshereC"}</userTabLayout>
            <userTabLayout id="B">{"id":"colidgoeshereD"}</userTabLayout>
        </table>
    </tables>
</userSettings>
```

I'm using the following PHP code to load the file (`DOMDocument`) and then `DomXpath` to traverse the document

```
<?php
...
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load ($filename);

    $xpath = new DomXpath($xmldoc);

    $x = $xpath->query("//tables/table");
    $y = $x->item(0);
...
?>
```

The `$y` variable now contains a `DOMElement` object, with a `nodeValue` attribute containing the string as follows:

```
["nodeValue"]=>
string(81) "
        {"id":"colidgoeshereX"}
        {"id":"colidgoeshereY"}
"
```

My question is, what happened to the `<userTabLayout>` node? Why do I not see this as a child node to the `<table>` node?  And if I wanted to access the `<userTabLayout id="B">` node, how would I do that?

Normally I'd read the documentation on this kind of stuff, but the official documentation on the official PHP page, is really sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, what happened to the `<userTabLayout>` node?

Nothing happened to it. The `<userTabLayout>` elements are child-elements of the **DOMElement** you have in `$y`.

> Why do I not see this as a child node to the `<table>` node?

Because you're not looking for child-nodes by using the `nodeValue` field.

> And if I wanted to access the `<userTabLayout id="B">` node, how would I do that?

By traversing the document, e.g. accessing the child nodes via the `childNodes` field (surprise).

> Normally I'd read the documentation on this kind of stuff, but the official documentation on the official PHP page, is really sparse.

That's because the DOM is documented by the W3C already, e.g. here: http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/

As that link is specification it might be a bit technical, so harder to work into, however you can consider it complete (e.g. check for realness if you need to know it). Once understanding that DOM is specified, you can related to any DOM documentation available, for example within MDN, even in Javascript (one of the two default implementations by W3C), it works similar in PHP (esp. for traversal or how Xpath works).

Have fun reading!

Comment: Yep. RTFM is always a good option, if you know where the FM is.

Comment: Here is anohter hint: Check on SO for the tags [tag:domdocument] and [tag:php] and then for answers by [*Gordon*](http://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) or [*ThW*](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2265374/thw). They often answer with good detail about the DOM and PHP knowledge.

Comment: You're on the right track with Xpath. It is the easy way to extract data from an XML DOM. It is a W3C standard, that is why it is not part of the PHP manual. But use `DOMXpath::evaluate()`, `query()` does only support expressions that return a node list. The same expressions work with `HTMLDocument::evaluate()` in modern browsers (except IE).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can work without the DomXpath.

```
$xmlS = '
<userSettings>
    <tables>
        <table id="supertable">
            <userTabLayout id="A">{"id":"colidgoeshereX"}</userTabLayout>
            <userTabLayout id="B">{"id":"colidgoeshereY"}</userTabLayout>
        </table>
        <table id="almost-supertable">
            <userTabLayout id="A">{"id":"colidgoeshereC"}</userTabLayout>
            <userTabLayout id="B">{"id":"colidgoeshereD"}</userTabLayout>
        </table>
    </tables>
</userSettings>
';

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->loadXml($xmlS);

$table1 = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName("tables")->item(0);
$userTabLayoutA = $table1->getElementsByTagName("userTabLayout")->item(0);
$userTabLayoutB = $table1->getElementsByTagName("userTabLayout")->item(1);

echo $userTabLayoutA->nodeValue; // {"id":"colidgoeshereX"}
echo $userTabLayoutB->nodeValue; // {"id":"colidgoeshereY"}
```

As you can see, you can access all elements, one by one, using `getElementsByTagName` and specifying what item do you want.

Comment: Good enough.  I think I'm just frustrated by the lack of good documentation for this library.  It's clearly a very powerful engine for navigating XML, but the documentation is lacking.

Comment: Yes, it's very frustrating when you have to *do your own way* when you'd could go on a very tracked and clean path.